# asp.net vb how to open a textbox when pressing on

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, textbox

I made a form that gets send to my email.
now there is a a droplist box in which there is an options of afew, lets say colors, and at the end there is the option "Other" in which I want a textbox to apear beanth so the client can write the "color" he wants.

anyidea how to make it?

Im using VBcode with ASP.NET

if you need my code please let me know

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `AutoPostBack=True`  and then handle `OnSelectedIndexChanged`  event. In the event handler check if the DropdownList.SelectedItem.Text="Others" and then show or hide the textbox.

Use update panel to avoid the full page postback.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DL1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Others</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false">
```

And in the codebehind

```
Protected Sub DL1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text = "Others" Then
        TextBox1.Visible = True
        Else
                TextBox1.Visible= False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: instead of Others, I put other before. <asp:ListItem>Others</asp:ListItem>
corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Here is Your DropDownList. Set the visible property to false at the start for your TextBox Control

```
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack=true>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

**C#** Code sorry i am bad at VB bt its simple .Hope you will understand.

```
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Other")
        {
            TextBox1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```